# How to build a flexible multiple type data system in Rust without cloning strings?

Tags: string, rust, type-conversion, polymorphism, borrowing

I want to build a system where data of different types (`i32`, `String`, ...) flows between functions that modify the data. For example, I want to have an `add` function that gets "some" data and adds it.

The `add` function gets something of type `Value` and if `Value` is an `i32`, it adds the two `i32` values, if it is of type `String`, it returns a string that combines both strings.

I know that this would be almost perfect for template programming (or whatever this is called in Rust, I'm coming from C++) but in my case I want to have small code blocks that handle the stuff.

As an example, with `f64` and `String`, using `Float` and `Text` as the names, I have:

```
pub struct Float {
    pub min: f64,
    pub max: f64,
    pub value: f64,
}

pub struct Text {
    pub value: String,
}

pub enum Value {
    Float(Float),
    Text(Text),
}
```

Now I want to implement a function that gets a value that is supposed to be a string and does something to it, so I implement the `to_string()` method for `Value`:

```
impl std::string::ToString for Value {
    fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        match self {
            Value::Float(f) => format!("{}", f.value).to_string(),
            Value::Text(t) => t.value.clone(),
        }
    }
}
```

Now the function would do something like:

```
fn do_something(value: Value) -> Value {
    let s = value.to_string();
    // do something with s, which probably leads to creating a new string

    let new_value = Text(new_string);
    Value::Text(new_value)
}
```

In the case of a `Value::Float` this would create a new `String`, then a new `String` with the result and return it, but in the case of a `Value::Text` this would clone the string, which is an unnecessary step, and then create the new one.

Is there a way where the `to_string()` implementation could create a new `String` on `Value::Float` but return the reference of `Value::Text`'s value?

Comment: *but return the reference* — what variant of `Value` would allow you to return a reference?

Comment: The issue that i have is a) i don't know if this is a good approach in Rust in general, but even if it is, b) the to_string() implementation has to clone the String, if it is already a String, which could be megabytes of data copied useless.

Comment: Implement `Into<Cow<str>>` perhaps, instead of  `ToString`. That way, it can return a new `String` from a `Float` and a `&str` from a `Text`.

Comment: I don't understand the point, that very unclear, why don't you just match `Value` and do your operation without use a string. String are very flexible but clearly not a efficiente way to do operation, this look like a javascript feature that you want use in Rust. You loose in every aspect.

Comment: You mean 'just match "value"' in the "do_something" function? That's not an option, there will be 100 if not 1000 of functions like this, as soon as i introduce a new type (e.g. Int) i will have to adapt them all. The Cow thing sounds good until now, i am new to Rust, i will see if something better comes up, but it is an option i guess.

Comment: @PeterHall after looking a bit into it, i think the Into<Cow<str>> thing is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much. Do you want to add it as answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "standard" way to deal with the possibility of either a `String` or a `&str` is to use a `Cow<str>`. COW stands for clone-on-write (or *copy*-on-write) and you can use it for other types besides strings. A `Cow` lets you hold either a reference or an owned value, and only clone a reference into an owned value when you need to mutate it.

There are a couple of ways you can apply this to your code:

1. You can just add an `Into<Cow<str>>` implementation and keep the rest the same.
2. Change your types to hold `Cow<str>`s throughout, to allow `Text` objects to hold either an owned `String` or a `&str`.

The first option is easiest. You can just implement the trait. Note that the `Into::into` accepts `self`, so you need to implement this for `&Value` not `Value`, otherwise the borrowed values would be referencing owned values that have been consumed by `into` and are already invalid.

```
impl<'a> Into<Cow<'a, str>> for &'a Value {
    fn into(self) -> Cow<'a, str> {
        match self {
            Value::Float(f) => Cow::from(format!("{}", f.value).to_string()),
            Value::Text(t) => Cow::from(&t.value),
        }
    }
}
```

Implementing this for `&'a Value` lets us tie the lifetime in the `Cow<'a, str>` back to the source of the data. This wouldn't be possible if we implemented just for `Value` which is good because the data would be gone!

---

An even better solution might be to use `Cow` in your `Text` enum too:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

pub struct Text<'a> {
    pub value: Cow<'a, str>,
}
```

This will let you hold a borrowed `&str`:

```
let string = String::From("hello");

// same as Cow::Borrowed(&string)
let text = Text { value: Cow::from(&string) };
```

Or a `String`:

```
// same as Cow::Owned(string)
let text = Text { value: Cow::from(string) };
```

Since `Value` now can indirectly hold a reference, it will need a lifetime parameter of its own:

```
pub enum Value<'a> {
    Float(Float),
    Text(Text<'a>),
}
```

Now the `Into<Cow<str>>` implementation can be for `Value` itself because referenced values can be moved:

```
impl<'a> Into<Cow<'a, str>> for Value<'a> {
    fn into(self) -> Cow<'a, str> {
        match self {
            Value::Float(f) => Cow::from(format!("{}", f.value).to_string()),
            Value::Text(t) => t.value,
        }
    }
}
```

Just like `String`, `Cow<str>` satisfies `Deref<Target = str>` so it can be used anywhere that a `&str` is expected, by just passing a reference. This is another reason [why you should always try accept `&str` in a function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40006220/493729), rather than `String` or `&String`.

---

Generally, you can use `Cow`s as conveniently as `String`s, because they have many of the same `impl`s. For example:

```
let input = String::from("12.0");
{
    // This one is borrowed (same as Cow::Borrowed(&input))
    let text = Cow::from(&input);
}
// This one is owned (same as Cow::Owned(input))
let text = Cow::from(input);

// Most of the usual String/&str trait implementations are also there for Cow
let num: f64 = text.parse().unwrap();
```